# How to detect a inhomogeneity region in image

Tags: image-processing, filter, image-segmentation

I have an image that includes object and background. However, the object appears some inhomogeneity region due to illumination. My work is that how to detect inhomogeneity region. Which is feature can represent it? Example: low inhomogeneity-high/low feature value....Thank you so much

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: This question has been cross-posted at DSP: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/how-to-detect-a-inhomogeneity-region-in-image

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want segment the object.

You can use the edges as a feature for inhomogeneity.

For instance applying the matlab canny edge detectorwith default settings you get:

[image]

[image]

Then fill the contours and perform a connected component analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, your result is not clear. It appears some unwanted lines that don't belong the object. BTW, my gold is that how to segment object from inhomogeneity image. So, I would like to find some feature to distinguish object region and background region

Comment: Your objects are as homogeneous as your background, so local inhomogeneity give you relatively little information. Could you post a few more images? It will help determine what are the features of your objects and your background.

Comment: These image are big heterogeneity properties. Let see the second image, it shows similar intensity (bottom left) with object. Let define which is heterogeneity "the intenisity of object and background are similar"